# Transfering attributes from polyline to polygon features using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

How can I transfer the fields and attributes from a polyline feature to a polygon feature in ArcGIS 9.3?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Spatial Join tool found in the Analysis ArcToolbox. This will create a new dataset with polyline attributes attached to the polygon.