# Preserve input attribute schema option NOT working when using Feature to Polygon in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, personal-geodatabase, data-management

I have successfully converted a polyline fc with 1,780 records into a polygon fc in ArcGIS 10.1, by using the tool: [Feature To Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000), but the output does not keep the attributes of the input fc (I have checked the optional button to do so)

Then, I found [Transfering attributes from polyline to polygon features using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78745/how-to-transfer-attribute-from-polyline-feature-to-polygon-feature), but is this the only option? because I don't want to run two tools.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be explained by the [documentation for Feature To Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003n000000):

> **Note**:
>
> The Preserve attributes parameter (the attributes parameter in
>   scripting) does not work and should not be used. It will not be
>   removed for backward compatibility of scripts or models. The output
>   attribute schema and field values for certain input combinations may
>   be produced as described below; most of them are unintended.